# Crear consulta de fechas SQL, "DesdeFecha- HastaFecha"

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Deseo hacer tres tipos de consultas SQL, la primera seria cuando tengo dos fechas, ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM inventario WHERE fechaInventario BETWEEN '2019-05-10' AND '2019-05-12'
```

esta obviamente ya la tengo, sin embargo me faltan las consultas en caso de que quisiera buscar solo a partir de una fecha en adelante hasta el momento actual y el caso que me muestre desde el inicio hasta un momento en especifico.

Comment: Hmm...puedes reusar el codigo y simplemente cambiar los parametros, o dejarlos como variables que ingresa el usuario. ¿Estas usando solo sql? , o estas usando tambien otro codigo (C# o php por ejemplo). Puedes crear ahí una funcion que pide al usuario una variable datetime, y luego usar esa variable en tu sentencia sql

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre solucion usando

```
WHERE FECHA >= FECHA_INICIO_INTRODUCIDA AND FECHA <= FECHA_FIN_INTRODUCIDA
```

Comment: Esto es exactamente lo mismo que between. Cual es la pregunta y cual la respuesta?